# PostgreSql : could not fork process : Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: linux, postgresql

I'm having issues on one of my postgreSQL servers.

It's under heavy load (thousands of connections) and the log if filled with :

```
LOG:  could not fork new process for connection: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Here are the limits of the PQSql main process :

```
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units
Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds
Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes
Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes
Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max processes             5000000              5000000              processes
Max open files            1048576              1048576              files
Max locked memory         67108864             67108864             bytes
Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks
Max pending signals       771249               771249               signals
Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes
Max nice priority         0                    0
Max realtime priority     0                    0
Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us
```

And here's the output of top:

```
top - 15:12:59 up 2 days, 20:14,  2 users,  load average: 5.24, 3.35, 2.75
Tasks: 8378 total,   7 running, 8371 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  2.5 us,  2.9 sy,  0.0 ni, 92.8 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  1.8 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem : 192839.8 total,  24722.1 free,  26324.5 used, 141793.2 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   4088.0 total,   4059.4 free,     28.6 used. 126460.6 avail Mem
```

I don't know at all what could possibly block fork().

Limits seem fine, memory is ok too.

It could be file limits getting hit. Because I see this :

```
root@mandrasoft-database-2:/home/ubuntu# lsof -u postgres | wc -l
2039732
```

Comment: Can you check `max_connections` settings in postgres conf? If you have access to the pgsql console as admin then check to see how many connections are there with this command: `select count(*) from pg_stat_activity; ` Do you what the application that using the database is doing? I am guessing it is opening connection and not closing it properly.